# How to identify which modules , dependencies add to testbed in angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working on angular unit test with jasmine framework, I have few questions related testing.

1. I'm bit confused with which modules need to add dependencies, providers and imports section in testbed.

   My constructor function as below in component.ts

   ```
   constructor(
       private employeeService: EmployeeService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
       private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private customerService: CustomerService, private logger: NGXLogger,
       private errorService: PagesService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
       this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
         const customerDetails = data.CustomerResolver;
   }
   ```

   How to choose which modules, imports goes to dependencies, providers and imports section?
2. I'm always getting errors on customerDetails on last line in the constructor, Im not sure the reason not to declaration proper modules in testbed. Can someone please provide solution/guidance to how to write unit test cases for inside constructor?

Comment: You should be mocking all external dependencies. For `router`, use `RouterTestingModule`. This is a great resource in learning Angular unit testing and getting up to speed: https://testing-angular.com/.